# How to compare a string with Dictionary keys to get their values into a variable?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Having this code:

```
            int calories = 0;
            String breakfast = "I´ve had bread and butter, orange juice and goat cheese";
            var food = new Dictionary<string, int>
            {
                ["bread"] = 150,
                ["coffee"] = 20,
                ["juice"] = 30

            };

            foreach (var item in food)
            {
                if (item.Key.Contains.()) //?? 
                {
                    calories += item.Value;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Your breakfast calories are"+ calories);
```

How could I check if any string contains any of the keys in the collection so I can add its value to the calories variable?

Comment: First break sentence up into a list of words and then check if each word is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if the given sentence contains the Key instead.  You can rewrite your loop this way:

```cs
foreach (var item in food)
{
  if (breakfast.Contains(item.Key))
  {
    calories += item.Value;
  }
}
```

Also make sure you convert the input sentence into lower-case to make it case insensitive (which is what you need based on the context above).

Comment: This solution  will not take care of possible duplicate words

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how is the complexity of your program/logic need to deal with, splitting `breakfast` into words could only work if your `food` dictionary contains the key which is single words only.

**First solution**: For your `food` dictionary contains keys with **single word** only such as:

- juice
- coffee

```
    int calories = 0;
    String breakfast = "I´ve had bread and butter, orange juice and goat cheese";
    var food = new Dictionary<string, int>{{"bread", 150}, {"coffee", 20}, {"juice", 30}};
    string[] wordList = breakfast.Split(' ').ToArray();
    
    foreach (var word in wordList)
    {
        foreach (var key in food.Keys)
        {
            if (word.ToLower().Contains(key.ToLower()))
            {
                calories += food[key];
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Your breakfast calories are " + calories);
```

**Second solution**: For your `food` dictionary contains keys with **single or multiple words** such as:

- bread
- orange juice
- apple pie

Thus, added an extension to find a possible duplicate of the item(s) in your `breakfast`, grab the indexes, and doing calculations.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int calories = 0;
    String breakfast = "I´ve had bread and butter, orange juice and goat cheese";
    var food = new Dictionary<string, int> 
    {
        {"bread", 150}, 
        {"coffee", 20}, 
        {"juice", 30}
    };
    
    foreach (var key in food.Keys)
    {
        // Find possible duplicate food in breakfast
        var foodIndexes = breakfast.AllIndexesOf(key).ToList();
        foreach (var index in foodIndexes)
        {
            calories += food[key];
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Your breakfast calories are " + calories);
}

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string searchstring)
    {
        int minIndex = str.IndexOf(searchstring, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        while (minIndex != -1)
        {
            yield return minIndex;
            minIndex = str.IndexOf(searchstring, minIndex + searchstring.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

FYI,

1. The way you create dictionary and initialize value will leads to syntax error.
2. The solutions above will solve possible duplicate words for example:

> I´ve had bread and butter, orange **juice**, apple **juice** and goat cheese